# Is it possible to use the same dns for 2 webapps

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I'm currently in the process of configuring 2 third party apps for a game called EVE Online, one of them is Pathfinder and the other is a corporation management app.

for example if I want to access Pathfinder my URL would be "mydomain.com/pathfinder", but if wanted to access the other app my URL would be "mydomain.com/otherapp".

Pathfinder is located in the DocumentRoot folder (/var/www/pathfinder) and the other app should be in the Document Root folder aswell (/var/www/otherapp)

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
# The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
# the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
# redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
# specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
# match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
# value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
# However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
ServerName mydomain.com

ServerAdmin admin@bfc.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/pathfinder

# Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
# modules, e.g.
#LogLevel info ssl:warn

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

# For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
# enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
# include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
# following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
# after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
#Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =mydomain.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Comment: Probably, assuming both of those applications live on the same server. One way would be to use an alias:  `Alias /otherapp /path/to/otherapp/docroot` while the `DocumentRoot` of your virtualhost points to whatever the docroot of the Pathfinder application is.  There's not enough detail in your question for more specifics than this.

Comment: DNS is only going to resolve the domain name, mydomain.com, to an IP address. It does not do rewrite redirections.  Check out http://unix.stackexchange.com/  as stackoverflow.com is about programming and not systems adminstration.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Pathfinder is located in DocumentRoot, I would rather have the other app in the DocumentRoot aswell instead of it being inside Pathfinder's folder

Comment: @RedCricket I'm sorry you are right I didnt know that there was a unix stackexchange

Comment: Then please add more details about exactly what the directory structures of these applications are and how you want them to be laid out.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I added the virtual hosts file, and explained how I want the directory structures to be

Comment: It does look like you only need to add `Alias /otherapp /var/www/otherapp` inside this `<VirtualHost>` block.